# SQL 2005 table data type "text" to nvarchar

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, type-conversion

I have this column `Remark` which is data type `text`. The longest length is 153.

So is it safe to say that if I change this column from `text` to `nvarchar(200)`, I won't lose any data?

```
SELECT LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM( CAST( Remark AS NVARCHAR(MAX) )))) FROM myTable
ORDER BY LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM( CAST( Remark AS NVARCHAR(MAX) )))) DESC
```

Comment: Please see my updated [answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/158375/30859) for example code.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know what data is there, then:

1. Don't use `LTRIM` or `RTRIM`
2. Use `DATALENGTH()` (for `NTEXT` add `/ 2` to the end of that) instead of `LEN`

Now, converting from either `TEXT` or `NTEXT` to `NVARCHAR` won't result in data loss if the length is the same or larger than what was calculated assuming what is mentioned above.

HOWEVER, the *real* issue isn't what data is there, it's what does the app allow for. If the app allows for more than 200 characters, then 200 isn't a safe choice. Make sure that all sources that can insert or update data in this column enforce a limit of 200 characters. If even one does not, then you need to work with the devs to make sure any sources of input are updated to reflect a limit of 200, or whatever you agree on (just because nobody has yet used even 200 characters doesn't necessarily imply that there isn't a valid case for going above that limit, if the app allows for it).

---

I just had the thought that there could be a slight issue with maximum row size since the `TEXT`, `NTEXT`, and `IMAGE` datatypes, by default, are a 16 byte pointer in the row with the actual data off row. Since you only get approximately 8060 bytes per row, if you were less than 400 bytes from that limit, then changing `TEXT` (requiring 16 bytes) to `NVARCHAR(200)` (requiring 400 bytes) could potentially result in an error. However, I just tried it and doesn't error; it allows for going above the 8060 byte limit (keep in mind that the max row size is still approx. 8060, but any extra data will be placed on ROW_OVERFLOW pages).

```
USE [tempdb];

-- DROP TABLE dbo.AlterColumnTest;
CREATE TABLE dbo.AlterColumnTest
(
  [ID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [EnglishSource] VARCHAR(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS,
  [EnglishText] TEXT COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS,
  [HebrewSource] VARCHAR(50) COLLATE Hebrew_CI_AS,
  [HebrewText] TEXT COLLATE Hebrew_CI_AS,
  [Spacer] CHAR(7500) NOT NULL DEFAULT ('')
);

DECLARE @TestString VARBINARY(100);
SET @TestString = 0x4120746573743A20C0C620CBE0E2E8EC20F0F4F92021;
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @TestString); -- A test: ÀÆ Ëàâèì ðôù !

INSERT INTO dbo.AlterColumnTest ([ID], [EnglishSource], [HebrewSource])
VALUES (1, @TestString, @TestString);

SELECT * FROM dbo.AlterColumnTest;

UPDATE dbo.AlterColumnTest
SET    [EnglishText] = [EnglishSource],
       [HebrewText] = [HebrewSource];

SELECT * FROM dbo.AlterColumnTest;

ALTER TABLE dbo.AlterColumnTest
  ALTER COLUMN [EnglishText] NVARCHAR(200) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS;

ALTER TABLE dbo.AlterColumnTest
  ALTER COLUMN [HebrewText] NVARCHAR(200) COLLATE Hebrew_CI_AS;

SELECT * FROM dbo.AlterColumnTest;

SELECT *
FROM   sys.columns sc
WHERE  sc.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.AlterColumnTest');
```

Values for `@TestString` taken from:

- [Code Page 1252 Windows Latin 1 (ANSI)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195054.aspx)
- [Code Page 1255 Windows Hebrew](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195057.aspx)

Comment: 100% agreed on the "issue is what the app allows" point.  That's a way bigger priority.

Answer (score 1):

You can test this by adding a new column to the table in your dev environment. 
The column (Remark_200) would be of type NVARCHAR(200).

Then, you'd simply insert the values from Remark into Remark_200 and compare them (via a Select statement with Remark = Remark_200 WHERE clause.  If they are equal, you're good.  If not, you can identify which ones aren't equal and go from there.

This can also be done via a temporary table if for some reason you don't have a Dev environment to test this on.